# FFMPEG shows error like unable to find a suitable output format for text

Tags: android, android-ffmpeg, video-watermarking

I guess command is not working properly here.

I am using [this project](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java)

```
-y -i /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20190623_153948.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/DejaVuSans.ttf: text='Stack' " /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/output2.mp4
```

The result expected is the video which I am giving as input should be processed and it should contain text Stack in it

Answer (score 0):

drawText's fontfile should have an absolute path of the font file. Your command says the font file's path is `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/DejaVuSans.ttf`, I believe that's not the case as you running from android. It should be some file from android storage.

Example:

```
drawtext=fontfile=/storage/emulated/0/fonts/truetype/DejaVuSans.ttf
```

if `DejaVuSans.ttf` file is under `/storage/emulated/0/fonts/truetype/` directory in your android device.

Comment: I don't have any font file on my device is it just issue of font file and whether can i remove it from the command..??

Comment: if I am removing all the properties defined for font then it is showing error initializing filter drawtext with args 'text=Stack'               -y -i /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20190623_153948.mp4 -vf drawtext=text='Stack' -codec:a copy /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/output2.mp4

Comment: not sure whether your FFmpeg support drawtext filter. To enable compilation of this filter, you need to configure FFmpeg with `--enable-libfreetype`. To enable default font fallback and the font option you need to configure FFmpeg with `--enable-libfontconfig`. To enable the text_shaping option, you need to configure FFmpeg with `--enable-libfribidi`.

Comment: how can configure ffmpeg with --enable-libfreetype,--enable-libfontconfig and --enable-libfribidi in android ..??

Comment: you have to recompile it with that.

Comment: but i am unable to find the way in which it can be done please write proper steps for the same that may help me to get through this.

Comment: FFmpeg compilation is a bit tricky, I suggest you first try it for your desktop and run some command on desktop. Then try it for android. Here are a few references
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/macOS
https://medium.com/@karthikcodes1999/cross-compiling-ffmpeg-4-0-for-android-b988326f16f2
https://hackernoon.com/android-ndk-my-experience-with-ffmpeg-93dd7e4b9269

Comment: Let me know, how it goes... it may seem a  bit daunting first, but gets easier as it goes.

Comment: i am unable to do that please guide me with regards to the project that i have mentioned in above link..!!

Comment: Steps you can follow 1. use writing mind's library as source 2. Recompile ffmpeg for android with necessary configs to generate `so` files 3. replace `so` files from writing mind's library with the new ones. 4. Modify writing minds source code as needed.

Comment: how can i recompile it in android ..??

Comment: Here are a few references https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/macOS https://hackernoon.com/android-ndk-my-experience-with-ffmpeg-93dd7e4b9269 https://medium.com/@karthikcodes1999/cross-compiling-ffmpeg-4-0-for-android-b988326f16f2

Comment: I directly want solution for android and that too working with this writing mind's library. if you have exact idea of how that can be done in android then please help me with this thing